# WebView in Android KitKat gets confused by @font-face rules

Tags: android, css, android-webview, font-face, android-4.4-kitkat

In order to use a custom font in an Android `WebView`, and to let it correctly apply styles such as bold or italic, I wrote the following `@font-face` rules:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyFont';
  src: url('file:///android_asset/fonts/MyFontRegular.ttf');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyFont';
  src: url('file:///android_asset/fonts/MyFontBold.ttf');
  font-weight: bold;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyFont';
  src: url('file:///android_asset/fonts/MyFontItalic.ttf');
  font-style: italic, oblique;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyFont';
  src: url('file:///android_asset/fonts/MyFontBoldItalic.ttf');
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic, oblique;
}
```

Coupled with more rules applied to some HTML elements, I had `WebView`s properly set up, and the HTML text I wanted to display was indeed properly styled.

```
body {
  font: 11px MyFont;
  color: rgb(59,59,59);
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
}
h1 {
  font: italic bold 15px MyFont;
  color: rgb(59,59,59);
}
h2 {
  font: italic 13px MyFont;
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: rgb(59,59,59);
}
p {
  font: 11px MyFont;
  color: rgb(59,59,59);
  margin: 0;
}
```

At least, they were until Android KitKat came over with its new Chromium/Chrome-based `WebView`. Testing on this version of the system (4.4.2, really), I noticed that all the text was rendered as oblique: that is, not only headers, as specified by CSS rules, but also paragraphs.

Dabbling with the `@font-face` rules, I discovered that just by eliminating all of them but the first the `WebView` in Android KitKat was able to correctly apply bold and italic styles on its own, while in previous versions of the operating system it was oblivious to them without the proper `@font-face` setup. As soon as I reintroduced the commented-out `@font-face` rules, the text was displayed in an oblique style again.

I ended up providing a different CSS resource for `v19`, but I would really like to know if there is a misunderstanding on my part about how `@font-face` works or it is a bug to blame KitKat for, and more generally which is the culprit of this unusual (at least to my eyes) behaviour.

Comment: @GuilioPiancastelli I'm looking at doing the same thing just now. Did you ever solve this? Or do you only need a single TTF file for the webview?

Comment: @Mark As I wrote, I used multiple TTF files for WebViews on pre-KitKat Android systems, just one TTF file for KitKat and onwards. I provided different CSS resources for different Android versions thanks to the v19 qualifier.